# Virtual host in Apache redirects to internet ( 301 error)

Tags: networking, virtualbox, apache2, virtualhost

I have one wm with ubuntu 18.04 and one network adapter set to NAT.

I have setup a virtualhost I created servidorweb.orange.sergitorres.com.conf in sites-avalaible and enabled using a2ensite.

Apache is running without problems.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName servidorweb.orange.sergitorres.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/errorweb.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/accesweb.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Also setup /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 servidorweb.orange.sergitorres.com
```

But when i type in Browser (Firefox):

127.0.0.1 -> it works -> shows default apache index.html

localhost -> it works showing default apache index.html

but when i type

servidorweb.orange.sergitorres.com, it goes to a site called [www.sergitorres.com](http://www.sergitorres.com), outside in internet.

If i anlayse the http request it says: Error 301 moved permanently
Seems that  header request is good with servidorweb.orange.sergitorres.com but response header comes from [www.sergitorres.com](http://www.sergitorres.com).

i want to teach virtualhosts, and dont know why it goes outside internet ( [www.sergitorres.com](http://www.sergitorres.com) is an internet address not a local or virtual host).

Any help would be apreciated

pd: also changed the name of hostname to servidorweb.orange.sergitorres.com

Comment: Many browsers will cache DNS lookups, which may cause this sort of issue if you have visited the main domain in the past. If you change the virtual host to `.local` instead of `.com`, you should see the correct page. Alternatively, you may want to set up a second browser that is used only for learning purposes 

Comment: Id try..we are using Firefox, maybe its a setting to reset this cache DNS ? CLear cache perhaps ? This site is very strange and i doubt anybody has gone there in the past. Its a personal site of someone not popular. How to setup a second brwoser ? You mean install a new browser ? Thanks